# How i use move to another page after successful validation of form using XMLHttpRequest because Header function is not wroking with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

Javascript:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhttp.readyState==4 && xhttp.status==200){
        document.getElementById("display_result").innerHTML=xhttp.responseText;
    }
};
document.getElementById('loading').style.display='block';
xhttp.open("POST", "users_process.php", true);

xhttp.setRequestHeader('X-Alt-Referer', 'dashboard.php');
xhttp.send(data);
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $execute_query=$data_access->Execute($query);
    if($execute_query==true){
        header("location: dashboard.php");
    }else{
        echo("<div id='error'>Some error occured during uploading Please try again</div>");
    }
?>
```

Comment: Redirecting on the serverside doesn't redirect on the clientside when you do an ajax request. If you want to redirect, there's no need for ajax, just use a form

Comment: Why not submit form without ajax if that's what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> XMLHttpRequest returns a DOMString that contains the response to the request as text,
>   or null if the request was unsuccessful or has not yet been sent.

So when you redirect on the serverside, you don't redirect on the client side; the request just returns whatever is echoed on the server side as response. What you can do is return a value (a string or a boolean) assuring that the query was OK. Then, on the client side, you can check for that value and perform a redirect using `window.location.href`.

Comment: if i use php echo function then how can i get that echo result as a normal text that i can use that result inside if statement and then inside if statement i use window.location.href ???

Comment: If the query was ok, you can echo a message, e.g. `echo ("true");` and then at the client-side you can check for this string inside onreadystatechange (`if(xhttp.responseText == "true")`), and redirect using `window.location.href = 'dashboard.php';`

Comment: Thanks you really helped me i used trim () function first it was not working but after its now working so really thank you to and all who commented on my post